# Utl_File.Fopen Exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm new of pl-sql and now I'm writing a pl-sql procedure (on Oracle11) that uses Utl_File.Fopen function, now I'm becaming crazy for the following exception.

This is my procedure:

```
Procedure MyFirstProcedure
    is
    begin

        --somethings others

        c_filename := 'test';
        v_handle := Utl_File.Fopen (
            location    => c_locationScript,
            filename    => c_filenameScript,
            open_mode   => 'w',
            max_linesize => 256 );
    exception
      when others then  
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);        
end MyFirstProcedure;
```

and I get the following exception:

```
Exception: SQLCODE=-29283  SQLERRM=ORA-29283: operazione file non valida
```

Now i do the following actions:

```
CALL dbms_java.grant_permission( 'MYUSER', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '/home/test', 'read' )
CALL dbms_java.grant_permission( 'MYUSER', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '/home/test', 'write' )
```

and in the filesystem both home and test have a rwx right, but I continue to get the exception.

Some suggestion on How can I to fix if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from Oracle's description of the error code:

```
Cause:   An attempt was made to 
read from a file or directory that 
does not exist, or file or directory 
access was denied by the operating system.
```

UTL_FILE can only access files residing in a folder mapped by a CREATE DIRECTORY command. Alternativily mapped by the init.ora parameter utl_file_dir. The folder as well as the files in it must be accessible to the oracle account on the server.

Dbms_java.grant... is only meant for privileges pertaining to stored java programs.

Comment: Can you give me an example about **Alternativily mapped by the init.ora parameter utl_file_dir.**?

Comment: Do I have to add the **utl_file_dir = /home/test** in my init.ora file?

Comment: Init.ora is the Oracle startup configuration file. Some of the parameters in it can be modified by the DBA at runtime, but I dont think utl_file_dir is one of them. In newer versions of Oracle RDBMS "create directory" is recommended as it does not require a server restart and also allows for creating different dirrctories for different users. But again - usually "create directory" requires a user with dba privileges. This link describes the details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm

Comment: Yes - thats right as far as I recall. And you can specify several folders with comma separation.

Comment: A better choice would be to use a DIRECTORY object since init.ora is A) deprecated and B) only read during Oracle startup so you have to shut down and restart to have the changes take affect. Try something like `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS '/home/test'`, then when opening the file you'd do something like `v_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location => 'TEST_DIR', filename => 'test', open_mode => 'w');`. Oh, and in your script you put the filename into a variable named `c_filename` but in your UTL_FILE.FOPEN call you passed in a variable named `c_filenameScript`. Best of luck.